# int32_t multiplication on ATTiny2313 clobbers variables

Tags: c, avr-gcc

I'm stumped by some of my variables getting clobbered on an ATTiny2313. Commenting out lines of my code one by one, the culprit seems to be the multiplication in this function:

```
int32_t bmp085_b5(int32_t ut) {
    int32_t x1, x2;
    x1 = (ut - (int32_t) ac6) * ((int32_t) ac5) >> 15;
    x2 = ((int32_t) mc << 11) / (x1 + (int32_t) md);
    return x1 + x2;
}
```

Either commenting out the `x1 = ...` line (and changing the reference to `x1` to `ut`), or changing the multiply operation to an addition fixes the variable clobbering. To be specific, the upper byte of `mc` is being zeroed. What am I missing here? It is probably something very very obvious and/or stupid, but I'm not seeing it...

The variables `ac5` and `ac6` are of type `uint16_t`, `mc` and `md` are `int16_t`.

Comment: Is this reproducible in a minimal test program with nothing but the above, or only as part of a larger program? I suspect you have a buffer overflow clobbering variables on the stack, and the multiplication is causing the compiler to have to discard values cached in registers (due to running out of registers) and having to reload them from the stack, thereby getting the clobbered values.

Comment: Ah, so it could be a lack of memory issue? I'll try to strip my code even more, to see if that helps--i.e., I'll remove the i2c stuff. But if that fixes it, the next problem is of course to get all of it to fit in memory!

Comment: The '2313 only has 128 bytes of RAM. Give a '4313 a try (256 bytes of RAM). That should tell you almost instantly.

Comment: Oh. With that little ram it might simply be a stack overflow/wraparound.

Comment: Ha! Fixed. You guys are lifesavers ;) I had "helpful" strings in my code to aid in debugging. I need to get used to the embedded mindset again. 128 bytes is really really tiny!